# Find saved data of SharePoint list in SQL Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, sql

Could you please halp my find saved data of SharePoint list in SQL Server?
Where is Sharepoint list data stored in SQL Server

Thanks in advance!
Have a greate day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [WSS_Content_portal].[dbo].AllUserData
WHERE tp_LIstId='935B9940-3063-49DC-90D8-2AEE147A069D'
```

Then parse xml data

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint data are stored in the relevant Content Database of web application in SQL server.

Check the article for tables in Content database: [Inside a SharePoint Content DB](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2010/12/20/inside-a-sharepoint-content-db/)

Comment: It’s a lot help for me